# Zero-width negative look-behind assertion does not work as intended

Tags: ruby, regex

Somehow the zero-width negative look-behind assertion - do not match ") if preceded by \ - does not work as intended.

This is what I have now:

```
text = <<EOT
h1=_("This is a test")
h2=_("This is a test \"quotes\"")
h3=_("This is a test (\"quotes\")")
EOT

text.scan(/_\("(.*?)(?<!\\)"\)/)

=> [["This is a test"], ["This is a test \"quotes\""], ["This is a test (\"quotes"]]
```

But the result should be:

```
=> [["This is a test"], ["This is a test \"quotes\""], ["This is a test (\"quotes\")"]]
```

The last match is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text does not contain any backslash(`\`)

```
text = <<EOT
h1=_("This is a test")
h2=_("This is a test \"quotes\"")
h3=_("This is a test (\"quotes\")")
EOT
puts text
```

prints

```
h1=_("This is a test")
h2=_("This is a test "quotes"")
h3=_("This is a test ("quotes")")
```

Escape backslashes or use following form:

```
text = <<'EOT'
h1=_("This is a test")
h2=_("This is a test \"quotes\"")
h3=_("This is a test (\"quotes\")")
EOT
puts text
p text.scan(/_\("(.*?)(?<!\\)"\)/)
```

prints

```
h1=_("This is a test")
h2=_("This is a test \"quotes\"")
h3=_("This is a test (\"quotes\")")
[["This is a test"], ["This is a test \\\"quotes\\\""], ["This is a test (\\\"quotes\\\")"]]
```